# UWP application hangs-up on BLEWatcher restart

Tags: uwp

My application is a headless UWP one running in Win 10 Iot build 10.0.17035.1000 on a Raspberry Pi3 SBC. For some time I was trying to solve application hang-up on BLEWatcher Start after Stop command.To simulate my application behavior I put some code in sample MS BluetoothAdvertisement solution and ran it as a stand-alone application on by Raspberry Pi 3 SBC. After about an hour the problem appeared- the application just hanged-up. I think that stopping the current BluettothLEDevice BLE charctersitics and disposing this object can be improved. Please advise me, what could be the problem. Here is my code:    public sealed partial class Scenario1_Watcher : Page
    {
        //-------------------------------------------------------

```
    private async void OnAdvertisementReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, 
                                                    BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        instalinkUUID = "";
        bool result = false;
        string message = "";          

        if (watcher.Status == BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherStatus.Started)
        {
            if (oneTime == false)
            {
                oneTime = true;
                watcher.Stop();
                rootPage.NotifyUser("BLEWatcher stopped!", NotifyType.StatusMessage);

                //
                // connect to the detected advertizing device!!!
                //
                device = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(eventArgs.BluetoothAddress);
                message = String.Format("BLE device with ID {0} is connected.", device.DeviceId);
                ETWLogging.LogToETWDiagnosticLoggingChannelProvider(message);
            }
            else
                return;
        }

        // We can obtain various information about the advertisement we just received by accessing 
        // the properties of the EventArgs class

        // The timestamp of the event
        DateTimeOffset timestamp = eventArgs.Timestamp;

        // The type of advertisement
        BluetoothLEAdvertisementType advertisementType = eventArgs.AdvertisementType;

        // The received signal strength indicator (RSSI)
        Int16 rssi = eventArgs.RawSignalStrengthInDBm;

        // The local name of the advertising device contained within the payload, if any
        string localName = eventArgs.Advertisement.LocalName;

        // Check if there are any manufacturer-specific sections.
        // If there is, print the raw data of the first manufacturer section (if there are multiple).
        string manufacturerDataString = "";
        var manufacturerSections = eventArgs.Advertisement.ManufacturerData;
        if (manufacturerSections.Count > 0)
        {
            // Only print the first one of the list
            var manufacturerData = manufacturerSections[0];
            var data = new byte[manufacturerData.Data.Length];
            using (var reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(manufacturerData.Data))
            {
                reader.ReadBytes(data);
            }
            // Print the company ID + the raw data in hex format
            manufacturerDataString = string.Format("0x{0}: {1}",
                manufacturerData.CompanyId.ToString("X"),
                BitConverter.ToString(data));
        }

        // Serialize UI update to the main UI thread
        await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            // Display these information on the list
            ReceivedAdvertisementListBox.Items.Add(string.Format("[{0}]: type={1}, rssi={2}, name={3}, manufacturerData=[{4}]",
                timestamp.ToString("yyyy MM dd hh\\:mm\\:ss\\.fff"),
                advertisementType.ToString(),
                rssi.ToString(),
                localName,
                manufacturerDataString));
        });

        //
        // simulate BLE device service processing
        //
        await Task.Delay(10000);

        //
        // disconnect BLE device
        //
        result = await DisconnectBLEDevice(device);

        message = String.Format("BLE device with ID {0} has been disconnected!", device.DeviceId);
        ETWLogging.LogToETWDiagnosticLoggingChannelProvider(message);

        if (watcher.Status == BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherStatus.Stopped)
        {
            watcher.Start();

            rootPage.NotifyUser("Try to start the BLEWatcher.", NotifyType.StatusMessage);

            await Task.Delay(1000);

            if (watcher.Status == BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherStatus.Aborted)
            {
                rootPage.NotifyUser("BLEWatcher aborted!", NotifyType.StatusMessage);

                message = "BLEWatcher aborted!";
                ETWLogging.LogToETWDiagnosticLoggingChannelProvider(message);
            }
            else if(watcher.Status == BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherStatus.Started)
            {
                rootPage.NotifyUser("BLEWatcher (re)started!", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
                oneTime = false;
            }
            else
            {
                rootPage.NotifyUser("BLEWatcher error!", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
            }
        }
        else if(watcher.Status == BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherStatus.Aborted)
        {
            rootPage.NotifyUser("BLEWatcher aborted!", NotifyType.StatusMessage);

            message = "BLEWatcher aborted!";
            ETWLogging.LogToETWDiagnosticLoggingChannelProvider(message);
        }
    }

    private async void OnAdvertisementWatcherStopped(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherStoppedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        string message = "";

        // Notify the user that the watcher was stopped
        await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            rootPage.NotifyUser(string.Format("Watcher stopped or aborted: {0}", eventArgs.Error.ToString()), NotifyType.StatusMessage);

            if (watcher.Status == BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherStatus.Aborted)
            {
                message = String.Format("Watcher aborted: {0}!!!", eventArgs.Error.ToString());
                ETWLogging.LogToETWDiagnosticLoggingChannelProvider(message);
                rootPage.NotifyUser(message, NotifyType.StatusMessage);
            }
        });
    }

    private async Task<bool> DisconnectBLEDevice(BluetoothLEDevice bleDevice)
    {
        bool result = false;
        string message = "";


        if (bleDevice == null)
        {
            message = "DisconnectBLEDevice(): BLE device is null!";
            rootPage.NotifyUser(message, NotifyType.StatusMessage);

            await Task.Delay(1000);

            return result;
        }

        try
        {
            result = await DisposeActiveServicesAndCharacteristics(device);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            message = String.Format("DisconnectBLEDevice(): exception: {0}- FAILED", ex.ToString());
            rootPage.NotifyUser(message, NotifyType.StatusMessage);
        }
        finally
        {
            bleDevice.Dispose();
            bleDevice = null;
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
        }

        return result;
    }

    private async Task<bool> DisposeActiveServicesAndCharacteristics(
                                BluetoothLEDevice device)
    {
        bool result = false;
        string message = "";

        if (device == null)
        {
            message = string.Format("DisposeActiveServicesAndCharacteristics(): " +
                                        "BLE device with ID {0} is null!", device.DeviceId.ToString());
            rootPage.NotifyUser(message, NotifyType.StatusMessage);

            return result;
        }

        if (device.ConnectionStatus == BluetoothConnectionStatus.Disconnected)
        {
            message = string.Format("DisposeActiveServicesAndCharacteristics(): " +
                                        "BLE device with ID {0} is disconnected!", device.DeviceId.ToString());
            rootPage.NotifyUser(message, NotifyType.StatusMessage);

            return result;
        }

        try
        {
            var services = await device.GetGattServicesAsync();

            if ((services == null) || ((services.Services.Count == 0)))
            {
                message = String.Format("DisposeActiveServicesAndCharacteristics(): GATT Services " +
                                            "for Instadose device with ID {0} are incorrect.",
                                                 device.DeviceId.ToString());
                rootPage.NotifyUser(message, NotifyType.StatusMessage);
                return result;
            }

            if (services.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Unreachable)
            {
                message = String.Format("DisposeActiveServicesAndCharacteristics(): Services " +
                                            "for Instadose device with ID {0} are unreachable.",
                                                device.DeviceId.ToString());
                rootPage.NotifyUser(message, NotifyType.StatusMessage);
                return result;
            }

            foreach (var service in services.Services)
            {
                // check if this service is active
                if (service?.Session.SessionStatus == GattSessionStatus.Active)
                {

                    // Not yet implemented in C#
                    // service?.GattSession.Close();

                    //service?.Dispose();
                }

                service?.Session?.Dispose();
                service?.Dispose();
            }

            result = true;
            message = String.Format("DisposeActiveServicesAndCharacteristics(): " +
                                        "Instadose device with ID {0} GATT " +
                                        "Services and Charteristics sucessfully disposed- PASSED",
                                            device.DeviceId.ToString());

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            message = ex.ToString();

            message = String.Format("DisposeActiveServicesAndCharacteristics(): exception: " +
                                        "{0} for device with ID {1}", message, device.DeviceId.ToString());
            rootPage.NotifyUser(message, NotifyType.StatusMessage);
        }

        return result;
    }
}

class ETWLogging
{
    static LoggingChannel lc = new LoggingChannel("My provider", null, new Guid("4bd2826e-54a1-4ba9-bf63-92b73ea1ac4a"));

    /// <summary>
    /// LogToETWDiagnosticLoggingChannelProvider
    /// </summary>
    public static void LogToETWDiagnosticLoggingChannelProvider(String message)
    {
        // get ETW trace for Device Portal display
        lc.LogMessage(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to reproduce your issue. Have you tested on the desktop?

Comment: When this problem happens an application restart does not re-enable the board Bluetooth capability. So I have to power down and up the board in order to re-enable Bluetooth . Why this happens?

Comment: I tested on Raspberry Pi 3 with version 10.0.17035.1000 for ~1.5 hours but not reproduced your issue. I edited the Scenario1_Watcher based on your question. You can find it [here](https://github.com/luyaok/BLEWatcher/blob/master/Scenario1_Watcher.xaml.cs).

Comment: Thank you Rita. Your code is virtually the same as mine. I am testing your code right now in a release mode as I did with mine and let you know the result.

Comment: Hi Rita. I just verified your code by running the sample application on Raspberry Pi 3 board as a standalone release one. After  ~1 hour the problem re-occurred. The application stopped to respond to device advertisements. Not only this, but in order to make the application (BLE) active again, I had to restart the device (OS). My BLEWatcher initialization settings are: InRangeThresholdInDBm = -70; OutOfRangeThresholdInDBm = -75; OutOfRangeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);  Did you try to run your version in release mode on Raspberry Pi 3 board for long time?

Comment: I currently tried two kinds of setting BLE AdvertisementFilter: AdvertisementFilter.Advertisement.ServiceUuids.Add(default16ByteGUID) and                       f.Advertisement.DataSections.Add(new BluetoothLEAdvertisementDataSection(6, ibuff)). The problem happens in  both cases the. Please let me know what filtering is correct.

Comment: Hi Paul, I still not reproduced your issue with release mode for running about 2 hours. Can you share your live process dump file of your app when the app hangs? You can download this file from device portal->Debug->Debug settings->Live process dumps.

Comment: Hi Rita. Here is the link to FileDropper I posted the live process dump file for the application: http://www.filedropper.com/liveum-2018-01-23-08-07-24

Comment: Hi Rita. I had a bug in DisposeActiveServicesAndCharacteristics(): even if the BLE device was disconnected, its services still it had to be disposed. This improved a little-bit the performance. But, after application running for certain time, got in the OnAdvertisementWatcherStopped() handler BLEWatcher aborted notification with eventArgs.Error showing "RadioNotAvailable". I tried to manually restart the BLEWatcher with the "Run" button but the  BLEWatcher remained in aborted state and the OnAdvertisementWatcherStopped() handler showed the same error. Please advise me how to fix this problem.

Comment: Hi Rita. I stopped and restarted the application debugging and the "RadioNotAvailable" error appeared immediately. Most likely something happened with the BLE stack. I had to stop debugging, restart the device from the Dashboard, and restart debugging. Then BLE advertisements started to be detected.

Comment: But even without this error the BLEWatcher after some time hangs-up. The last time, after this happened, Win 10 IoT restarted by itself.

Comment: Hi Rita. Please find the BluetoothAdvertisement application live process dump file here: http://www.filedropper.com/liveum-2018-01-24-15-30-03

Comment: Hi Rita. A colleague of mine just did let me know that he had the same problem with the BLEWatcher stall (hang-up). He uses, like me, the latest Windows Insiders Preview build but from a laptop with a Bluetooth stick. This narrows the possible cause of this problem to the current BLE Stack (or interfacing with it) in Win 10 IoT and not to the hardware platform or the Bluetooth chip. We hope that the Win 10 IoT team will fix this issue as soon as possible. Please let us know. We have to deliver our applications for production.

Comment: I'll report it internally. You can submit an issue via feedback hub.

Comment: Thanks Rita. Recently I posted the problem description here:                    https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/358bde44-502c-43fb-990b-47cb7a9db560/uwp-application-hangsup-on-blewatcher-restart?forum=wdk

Comment: @PaulTomov I also not able to reproduce this issue with OS Windows 1o IoT core(16299) and Windows Insider Preview(17083) on  Raspberry Pi3 . Are you able to reproduce this issue using the sample code bluetoothadvertisement without custom code? And if it is convenient, can you also reproduce this issue on the Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 17083?

Comment: Actually I reproduced this issue on Win 10 IoT build 17083 Insiders Preview on Raspberry Pi 3 SBC using the same MS BluettothAdverisement sample application and reported it to MS. For a proof I attached the application dump file as in the link above: filedropper.com/liveum-2018-01-24-15-30-03 .

Comment: Here is the link to my simulation code, based on BluettothAdverisement sample application, Scenario1_Watcher.xaml.cs   http://www.filedropper.com/scenario1watcherxaml. With the build 17083 I started to see also the exception:                           System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range. Please test this code.

Comment: And here is the dump file from todays testing: http://www.filedropper.com/liveum-2018-02-13-09-06-01

Comment: My Raspberry Pi3 SBC Win 10 IoT Core was updated by MS online to build 10.0.17093.1000. I just retested the same BluetoothAdverisement sample application modified with my simulation code. The BluettothLEWatcher hang up problem appeared very soon. Please see the uploaded dmp file (http://www.filedropper.com/liveum-2018-02-15-08-29-59) and the screenshot from the Windows Device Portal (http://www.filedropper.com/bluetoothadvertisement-radionotavalable).

Comment: I would like to clarify a couple of things: 1- I am using the Raspberry Pi 3 Broadcom chip BCM43438 for BLE communications. 2-

Comment: I am aware that there is a problem with the Bluetooth low-level driver for this chip https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1a1aa853-76d0-415e-bda5-82ff353e0893/win-10-iotcore-raspberry-pi3-bluetooth-driver-issue-a-workaround?forum=WindowsIoT) . Did Broadcom and MS fix this issue and is this fix reflected in the latest Win 10 IoT Core build?

Comment: This is the Bluetooth adapter data I got in PowerSchell from the Raspberry Pi 3 by running "devcon find =Bluetooth": BCMBTBUS\BLUETOOTH\3&2113EC42&0&4097                        : Bluetooth Radio

Comment: @PaulTomov When you got this issue, were you debuging the UWP application using Visual Studio? If not, please try to debug the UWP app with Visual Studio to see if there is any exception or error code return to help troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: H Fei, Yesterday I applied the workaround described in the link I referred to on 2/23/18 by replacing the BCM43438 chip Bluetooth device with a CSR 4.0 Bluetooth dongle. Then I started your BluetoothAdvertisement application again in debug mode from VS 2017. It still works without a single error for more that 12 hours. This proofs again that there is a serious bug in the BCM43438 Bluetooth stack MS and Broadcom must fix.

Comment: Hi Fei, I already tested Win 10 IoT core build 10.0.17115.1 for the BLEWatcher problem. It seems that the behavior has been improved but after a couple of hours the BLEWatcher simply stops working and the application stalls. Please let me know when the BLEWatcher problem will be solved. Thanks. Unfortunately, despite that the CSR 4.0 Bluetooth dongle doesn't cause hang-up, but after a short time it starts reporting "device unreachable" which is also a serious problem.

Comment: Even with  Win 10 IoT core build 10.0.17115.1 the BLEWatcher problemexists; your sample application works shortly and then reports: Error = RadioNotAvailable.